# What does こっちの方 refer to here?

Tags: meaning

> これは、叩いて返せばいいのか。
>
> おう。ぶっ叩いて相手にぶち込んで、相手が落とせば勝ちだぜ。
>
> なるほど。お前は**こっちの方**が良さそうだな…俺も、手加減無しでいこう。

My question is about what こっちの方 refers to here. It seems that they are playing a game where one has to hit the ball and the other has to catch it without dropping it or they lose and this goes on in turns. The above excerpt starts after the first person to talk had the ball kicked at them(and them getting knocked over). Is こっちの方 in this case referring to his current role in the game(the hitter), and he is now saying that he gets the impression that the other person is going to be better at doing this than him?

edit(Additional lines):

あはははは。…それよりにーちゃん。どう？

…どうとは？

ボクの水着姿。せくしーだろ？

"せくしー"？

色っぽいかどうか、ってコト。

む…なるほど…

で、どう？

そうだな。"せくしー"だ…と、思う…

むっ。今、目を反らしたな！そんなにーちゃんには、こーだっ！

むっ…！？

見たか…

…って、ありゃ？もしかしてやりすぎた？

…なに。この程度なら問題ない。

おー、やるやるー。流石ボクが認めたにーちゃんだぜ。

and then this is where the rest of the conversation starts.

Comment: I find no decisive clue within your question. Could you provide more contexts before the lines? If it comes from a manga or anime, a pic would be of more help.

Comment: Is it a 1 vs 1 game or 2 vs 2? Are ボク and にーちゃん teammates in this game?

Comment: Are you the same person? You can merge your account. See http://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts (もう離れちゃってますが…)

Answer (score 1):

As broccoli forest is saying, there's just not enough context here to be able to accurately answer your question.

こっち (this one) implies that there's something else comparable in this context (あっち), but none of the text you copied in this question fits that something else.

If I'd venture a guess, that something else refers to another game, and therefore こっち means this game. Or this whole dialog is from a manga, and こっち and あっち both refers to something they are holding, for example.